# i can't shoot the bullet in this pygame space invaders

Tags: python, pygame

Pygame is perfectly installed, everything else is working fine spaceship movement and enemy movement but i am not able to see the bullet which i have drawn from inside the fire_bullet function, I have tried drawing it from outside the function and that does seem to work .

```
import pygame
import os
import random
pygame.init()

#Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders ')
UFO = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets2', 'ufo.png'))
pygame.display.set_icon(UFO)


#player

playerImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets2', 'spaceship.png'))
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
VEL = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


#enemy
enemyImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets2', 'enemy.png'))
enemyimg1 = pygame.transform.scale(enemyImg, (45, 50))
enemyX = random.randint(0,800)
enemyY = random.randint(50,150)
enemyX_change = 0.7
enemyY_change = 40

def enemy(x,y):
    screen.blit(enemyimg1, (x, y))

#background
bg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets2', 'space.png'))

#bullet
bulletimg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets2', 'bullet.png'))
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"  #Ready - Rest, Fire - Motion

def fire_bullet(x,y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x+16, y+10))


run = True

#Game loop

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # Movement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                VEL = -1.4
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                VEL= 1.4
            # Bullet positioning
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)



        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                VEL = 0

    playerX += VEL

    # Restricting boundaries of spaceship
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    enemyX += enemyX_change

    # Restricting boundaries of Enemy
    if enemyX <= 0:
       enemyX_change = 1
       enemyY += enemyY_change
    elif enemyX >= 736:
        enemyX_change = -1
        enemyY += enemyY_change

    #Bullet Movement
    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change


    screen.fill((255,255,0))
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))

    player(playerX, playerY)

    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Also all the assets are fine and dowloaded correctly so idk why is it still not showing the bullet drawn from inside the function

Comment: if you run the loop at 1 frame per second, you can very well see that the bullet is there, you need to limit your loop speed so that it doesn't run at max speed (use `pygame.time.Clock`), also do you know where y of value 50 is? it is the top of the screen, also you need to reset the bullets y pos, I really tho suggest that you take a look at some tutorials or even other questions on this site that already have been answered on how to shoot bullets

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet is so fast that you can barely see it. You have to limit the frames per second. Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.
The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

e.g.:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Game loop
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]
```